# Add new field to every document in Mongo Collection through Java

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

How can I add a new field to every document in an existent collection?

This is what I have tried so far

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("myDB");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("myCollection");
DBObject test = new BasicDBObject();
DBObject add = new BasicDBObject();
add.put("xxx", "newField");
collection.update(add, test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use update multi:

```
    DBObject queryAll = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject newValue = new BasicDBObject("xxx", "newField");
    DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", newValue);
    collection.updateMulti(queryAll, update);
```

Comment: Used your code, but new field is not getting appended to all jsons

Comment: is it append to some of the documents? or not at all?

Comment: Code seems correct, but it's not at all appending the field to json

Comment: Does collection.find() returns any documents?

Comment: If I use for loop in this context, everything will be overridden by last value. You think is there a way to update them one by one?

Comment: I am not sure If I know what you mean. Can you send some code? If you use loop than dont use updateMulti bud use only update. This will update only one document, that is found by the query.